# What is the correct term for decorations on a spacecraft?

Tags: terminology, festooning

Many spacecraft have been decorated or embellished with logos, slogans, names of people or research groups, or small stowaway items.  **Does NASA have a term for this practice?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Festooning

> NASA's Perseverance Mars rover isn't just shuttling sophisticated science instruments and tubes to be filled with Earth-bound rock samples. It's carrying symbols, mottos, and objects that range from practical to playful - everything from meteorite fragments to chips carrying the names of 10.9 million people.
>
> The "extras" are part of a tradition that harks back to the early space age and is **now called "festooning" in NASA lingo**. A plaque aboard Pioneer 10 and 11 displays a man and a woman for distant spacefarers who might find the spacecraft. The Golden Record aboard Voyager 1 and 2 serves a similar purpose. Metal from the wreckage of the Twin Towers on 9/11 was installed on the rovers Opportunity and Spirit, while Spirit also carried a memorial to the crew of Space Shuttle Columbia.
>
> [source](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/5-hidden-gems-are-riding-aboard-nasas-perseverance-rover)

Comment: And if you've ever been festooned, you know how painful that came be.

Comment: Would this include the livery they put on aircraft---all the colors they paint the body in?

Comment: @user39728: The source article does not say either way.  It seems that the distinction is whether the designers consider a feature to be an "extra".